# Removing a varying substring from strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, text

I have a text file that lists addresses as follows.

```
123 Fake Street City State, Zip
124 Fake Street City State, Zip
...
```

I wrote a C# program that trims out the beginning numbers and filters out the streets (I am looking for unique streets in the data).  However, when there is an apartment in the address, they read like this.

```
123 Example Street Apt 12B City State, Zip
123 Example Street Apt 12C City State, Zip
```

With the way my code is written (since it looks for **fully unique** rows), it does not eliminate these apartment numbers.  What I want to do is remove the "apt" and ONLY the substring that follows it.  The problem is, these apartment numbers can be any length.  What would I put in the code below to remove apt + the apartment number?

```
if (line.ToLower.Contains(" apt "))
{
    //Remove apt + substring following it
}
```

Comment: There's no easy solution for this. What if the address is "123 Example Street Unit 12B" or "123 Example Street Suite 12B"?

Comment: Are you sure the value which your are showing always will be in this same structure or it might change ? Please elaborate it first

Comment: This list is only going to be needed once, so changing structure is not an issue.  Its OK if some of them are omitted because they're sorted and I can sift through them...I just don't want to manually delete all of these if I can help it.  There are no "suites", "apartments", or any other wordings other than apt, at least not that I had found.

Comment: I wish people that create list like this would think of the ones that have to parse it... Be carefull when you parse, a street name could contain the characters "apt": 123 lapton street City State

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know there will be a space after the apartment number, you can do this:

```
int aptStartIndex = line.ToLower().IndexOf(" apt ");
int aptEndIndex = line.IndexOf(" ", aptStartIndex + 5);
line = line.Substring(0, aptStartIndex) + line.Substring(aptEndIndex);
```

The first line finds the start of the "apt" string.
The second line finds the next space after " apt ".
The third line takes the substring up to " apt ", and adds the substring after the word after " apt ", effectively removing the two words.

I tested it [HERE](http://ideone.com/TaMMal).

Comment: This will not remove the substring following "Apt" (Apt. number).

Comment: @It'sNotALie. What about Apt 1?  aptEndIndex will still be positioned right, won't it? (If you mean my missing `ToLower`, I just fixed that.)

Comment: @ataravati I think your comment was for my post before I fixed a mistake.  Do you still see an issue?

Comment: The regular expressions method doesn't seem to work fully...there are a few more results left.  This method found all but the few results (about 120) where the apt and apartment number were crunched together.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegEx `" Apt \w+ "` to remove the apt and the number following it:

```
Regex.Replace("123 Example Street Apt 12C City State, Zip"
              ,@" Apt \w+"
              ,"" 
              ,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better just to use Regex for this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input,
    @"apt\W[0-9]+[a-z]?\W", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, if the word for apartment can vary, the regex gets a ton more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example although the regex way is probably best.

```
        if (line.ToLower().Contains(" apt "))
        {
            String[] sParts = line.Split(' ');
            string finishedLine = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < sParts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sParts[i].ToLower().Equals("apt"))
                {
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    finishedLine += sParts[i] + " ";
                }
            }
            line = finishedLine.Trim();
        }
```